# Echarts Sunburst Child with 2 Parents

Tags: echarts

I'm trying to create a sunburst where a child element can overlap 2 parent elements, like in the picture below. However, I haven't been able to find any way of recreating this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for any help anyone can offer!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont need special sunburst funcionalities you could use multiple pie charts:

```js
option = {
  series: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: ['45%', '70%'],
      label: {
        position: 'inside'
      },
      data: [
        { value: 1048, name: 'Area 1' },
        { value: 735, name: 'Area 2' },
        { value: 580, name: 'Area 3' },
        { value: 484, name: 'Area 4' },
        { value: 300, name: 'Area 5' }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'pie',
      startAngle: 20,
      radius: ['20%', '45%'],
      label: {
        position: 'inside'
      },
      data: [
        { value: 1048, name: 'Parent 1' },
        { value: 735, name: 'Parent 2' },
        { value: 580, name: 'Parent 3' },
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Here is an [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-borderRadius&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsDOBTAThLGAXLANprrLkWxgCeIWxA5CPkwDRUU4CGAJhACuRUkwAsAVgCkHWEwDsABhkBdTtXQQwWALYBlOgBtGlDRQBGwHH1wAlfkJEBGRerOxL13AGFghq8wAxABmoRxc1J42OADqEHxgABbEAEwRsAC-btSGPOZYhsSo7rAgwBhaUNDMENAVNkzpWel8PGA8xGQlSLAAbjyGgiYuYgAc7LDQPDomTACCOFg8sE5MmdkaPf2DJvIAzBITUzPMC0uwKWvN3X0DQ8QSo66T07Nny3tXG9RbdyZjYiOr1Oi2WYi-6XQvx2xD2imexzeoNgEiu6RUXGuFGKGjoDGYrCw4TMGHaODAc2gAHNjKlXOleAJhJ0mCllLJxNImGp0lpdAZaLTTO4onYHMyVvSSqKcL5_DggqFgsSRVZonEEskLk1vrBcvlCsKzGUKpAYDU6vEiTqWm0OqRIchbjDJWMgSc5AAFHiLaBgFYQm7be6wfaHF4epje33-y7rR3QkOPBHAr0-rB-2CfeNmDHUDLkDEZADcQA).

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you very much for taking the time to reply and produce a demonstration!